# ¿Como iniciar un programa en una fecha determinada y esto configurarlo en el mismo programa con c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows, visual-studio-2015

Desarrolle una aplicación en c# para el trabajo y como requerimiento necesito configurarla para que se inicie en una fecha determinada, esto debo poder establecerlo en un formulario ingresando la fecha y día (en la misma aplicación), osea no debe estar en ejecución para que la instrucción se lanze...

Código:

```
string Dia = comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        short hra = Convert.ToInt16(textBox4.Text);
        short min = Convert.ToInt16(textBox3.Text);


        using (ScheduledTasks Tareas = new ScheduledTasks())

        {
            Task tarea = Tareas.CreateTask("Ejecutar secador de botas");

            tarea.ApplicationName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Fishken SB\SecadorDeBotas           \SecadorBotas.exe";

            tarea.Comment = "Tarea que ejecuta programa secador de botas";            

            tarea.Creator = "USER";

            tarea.Priority = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.Normal;

            switch (Dia)
            {
                case "Lunes":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Monday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;
                case "Martes":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Tuesday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;
                case "Miercoles":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Wednesday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;

                case "Jueves":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Thursday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;
                case "Viernes":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Friday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;
                case "Sabado":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Saturday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;
                case "Domingo":

                    tarea.Triggers.Add(new WeeklyTrigger(hra, min, DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday));

                    tarea.Save();

                    MessageBox.Show("Configuración guardada!!");

                    break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Y si el programa no esta vivo, quien lo va a lanzar? como va a saber la fecha y el momento donde debe prenderse? no, los programas no funcionan asi. Vas a tener que tener un servicio que lo lance en ese momento.

Comment: El Task Scheduler de Windows tiene un API, de hecho si buscas en github vas a encontar algunas librerías que te permiten usar de forma mas fácil la API desde c#.

Answer (score 0):

Una de las soluciones es si lo realizaste como **Servicio de Windows**, configuras desde windows la hora y fecha que se debe ejecutar con el `Task Scheduler` o en español `Programador de Tareas`. En el caso que no sea como **Servicio Windows** y es un **WinForm** (pero este tiene el proceso para que inicie automaticamente luego de su ejecución) lo que deberias hacer es un instalador para el mismo, instalarlo y luego configurar el `Task Scheduler` o en español `Programador de Tareas`.

Comment: Ok Sebastian gracias.

Comment: Cree un Task pero no hace nada y no veo el error, tampoco arroja alguno:

Comment: Podras agregar una imagen de como configuraste la tarea programada? sin eso no podria visualizar el error.

Comment: Agregue el código en la descripción del problema Sebastian...

Comment: No de Código, sino de la tarea programada, porque puede ser por eso. Ademas deberías verificar si le diste los permisos correspondientes al aplicativo.